# Plot a column of timestamps in a timeline axis along with counts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, timestamp

I have a dataframe with a single column: 'date'. This column has a bunch of timestamps (around 500,000) in some cases, with some repeated ones. I want to plot a graph with timestamps in the x-axis, and count of these timestamps in y-axis.

I have tried a simple plot command with almost the perfect result:

```
df.value_counts(sort=False).plot(kind='bar',figsize=(20,10))
```

[image: Result]

As you can see, the x-axis is all squished together, this might have been because the timestamps were in string format but I have since converted them into timestamps. Is it possible to have a timescale in the x-axis and plot the number of times these timestamps appear in the y-axis, with blank spaces at times when there are no timestamps.

This is what the dataframe looks like:

```
2017-07-06 12:00:43
2017-07-06 12:00:43
2017-07-06 12:00:53
2017-07-06 12:00:53
2017-07-06 12:00:53
                ...        
2017-07-06 20:03:43
2017-07-06 20:03:43
2017-07-06 20:03:43
2017-07-06 20:04:05
2017-07-06 20:04:05
Name: date, Length: 17105, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

And this is what it looks like when I run `value_counts()` on it:

```
2017-07-06 17:47:23    99
2017-07-06 16:54:54    93
2017-07-06 16:12:10    53
2017-07-06 19:42:33    48
2017-07-06 15:56:54    35
                       ..
2017-07-06 14:18:03     1
2017-07-06 17:31:33     1
2017-07-06 14:17:58     1
2017-07-06 14:17:20     1
2017-07-06 16:26:06     1
Name: date, Length: 6399, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Do you really want value counts down to the per second level?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `matplotlib` to plot, and set the ticks interval with `set_major_locator`, for example

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
time = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018 12:00:00', freq='20S', periods=50)
count = np.random.randint(0, 5, 50)
ax.stem(time, count)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.SecondLocator(interval=200))
plt.show()
```

[image]